# Given a person's allergy score, determine whether or not they're allergic to a given item, and their full list of allergies using c

Tags: c

Given a person's allergy score, determine whether or not they're allergic to a given item, and their full list of allergies.

An allergy test produces a single numeric score which contains the information about all the allergies the person has (that they were tested for).

The list of items (and their value) that were tested are:

eggs (1)
peanuts (2)
shellfish (4)
strawberries (8)
tomatoes (16)
chocolate (32)
pollen (64)
cats (128)
So if Tom is allergic to peanuts and chocolate, he gets a score of 34.

Now, given just that score of 34, your program should be able to say:

Whether Tom is allergic to any one of those allergens listed above.
All the allergens Tom is allergic to.
Note: a given score may include allergens not listed above (i.e. allergens that score 256, 512, 1024, etc.). Your program should ignore those components of the score. For example, if the allergy score is 257, your program should only report the eggs (1) allergy.

```
int main()
{
    int score;
    printf("Enter the score:");
    scanf("%d",&score);
    if(score >1024)
    {
        score -= 1024;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 512 && score<1024)
    {
        score -= 512;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 256 && score <512)
    {
        score -= 256;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 128 && score <256)
    {
        score -= 128;
        check_allergies(score);
         score = 128;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if (score > 64 && score < 128)
    {
        score -= 64;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 64;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if (score > 32 && score <64)
    {
        score -= 32;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 32;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if (score > 16 && score <32)
    {
        score -= 16;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 16;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 8 && score < 16)
    {
        score -= 8;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 8;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 4 && score < 8)
    {
        score -= 4;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 4;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 2 && score < 4)
    {
        score -= 2;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 2;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else if(score > 1 && score < 2)
    {
        score -= 1;
        check_allergies(score);
        score = 1;
        check_allergies(score);
    }
    else
        check_allergies(score);
}
void check_allergies(int score)
    {
    if (score == 1)
        printf("Egg");
    else if(score==2)
        printf("Peanuts");
    else if(score==4)
        printf("Shellfish, ");
    else if(score==8)
        printf("Strawberries, ");
    else if(score==16)
        printf("Tomatoes, ");
    else if(score==32)
        printf("Chocolate, ");
    else if(score==64)
        printf("Pollen, ");
    else if(score==128)
        printf("Cats, ");
    else
        printf("No disease");
    }
```

I am almost getting correct answer for values like 130,33,68 etc. But for numbers like 35, 133 etc. i am not getting the correct answer, may be they are not in the check_allergies condition testing. I can write each and every condition in check_allergies function like for score==3,score==5 etc. but it will increase the line of codes. Can you help me to get this done in some other way?

Comment: Tip: Check the pattern of the numbers, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc... does that seem at all familiar to you? The answer for doing this in an easy way lies in there.

Comment: Do you know *why* you're not getting the correct answer for 35?

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!  1) it is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  2) there is no prototype for `check_allergies()` before it is called.

Answer (score 2):

The allergies are coded as a bit scheme occupying 8 bits (1 byte).

To ignore score components not in your range, you can AND the input score with `0xff`.

To test if an allergy has been coded in the input, you can AND it with the bit.

Examples:

```
#define eggs 1
#define peanuts 2
#define shellfish 4
#define strawberries 8
#define tomatoes 16
#define chocolate 32
#define pollen 64
#define cats 128
```

Or:

```
#define eggs         0x01
#define peanuts      0x02
#define shellfish    0x04
#define strawberries 0x08
#define tomatoes     0x10
#define chocolate    0x20
#define pollen       0x40
#define cats         0x80
```

To ignore undefined allergy parts:

```
int allergies= input & 0xff;
```

To test an allergy, you check if the bit is set:

```
if (allergies & cats) {
    // allergic to cats
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using bitmaps as proposed by other answers is a very good idea and highly recommended, but here the answer why your original program does not work correctly:

```
else if(score > 128 && score <256)
{
    score -= 128;
    check_allergies(score);  /* HINT 1 */
    score = 128;             /* HINT 2 */
    check_allergies(score);
}
```

HINT 1: this is why it works e.g. for 129 - if the remainder (1) is a valid allgergy code, it will output that allergy name.

HINT 2: this is why it doesn't work e.g. for 131 - the line HINT 1 does not produce the right output (because 3 is not a code for a allergy), and now `score` is set to `128`, so every other allergy code that was coded in `score`is lost.

Replace this block (and similar blocks) with this construct and it will work.

```
else if(score >= 128 && score <256)
{
    check_allergies(128);  /* HINT 1 */
    score -= 128;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a task very suitable for bitmasks.

Here is a short example:

```
// The bit masks, note that they are powers of two
const int egg=1;
const int peanuts=2;
const int shellfish=4;

// How we check if allergic to peanuts
if(score & peanuts) 
    printf("Peanuts, ");
```

It works because any power of two will in binary be one `1` and the rest will be zeros. `score & peanuts` will return the number where all bits are zero except for those that are one in BOTH `score` AND `peanuts`. And if there is at least one bit that is set to one, this will be a non-zero number and thus, `score & peanuts` will be evaluated to true.

So there's really no need to decrement `score` over and over again.

Here is a short snippet demonstrating it:

```
void check_allergies(int score)
{
    const struct {
        int mask;
        char *name;
    } allergies[] = {{1, "Egg"},
               {2, "Peanuts"},
               {4, "Shellfish"}
    }; // Just add more allergies in this array

    if(score == 0) {
        printf("No allergies");
        return;
    }   
    
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof allergies/sizeof allergies[0]; i++){
        if(score & allergies[i].mask)
            printf("%s, ", allergies[i].name);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int score;
    printf("Enter the score:");
    if(scanf("%d",&score) != 1) { // Always check scanf for error
        perror("Error reading score");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    check_allergies(score);
}
```

Comment: Judging from the contents of the question, OP may not have knowledge of bitwise operators or how they work or possibly even how numbers are represented in binary, and likely does not have knowledge of arrays, structures, `sizeof`, and possibly loops.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Possibly, but someone else might benefit from it.